# ttf2eot - What is the input path on Mac OS X?

Tags: css, shell, command-line

i use Mac OS X Lion and installed MacPorts and the tool ttf2eot to convert .ttf fonts to .eot.

When i use it as described here: http://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/ i get the error:

```
-MacBook-Pro:~ $ ttf2eot < pacifico.ttf > pacifico.eot
-bash: pacifico.ttf: No such file or directory
```

In which folder pacifico.ttf has to be in order to be found ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter a file name on the command line like that, it looks in the current folder for the file.

```
ttf2eot < pacifico.ttf > pacifico.eot
```

Is looking for `pacifico.ttf` in the current folder, which is `~` (your home folder) in this case.

You can also use an absolute path:

```
ttf2eot < /path/to/pacifico.ttf > pacifico.eot
```